# Do I have the right to be forgotten on SE?

Tags: discussion, legal

Does Stack Exchange provide any option to be forgotten? Under [article 17](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/) users have the right to be forgotten, but I'm unsure how this works legally with Stack Overflow.

What if I want to enact that right to have my account, and all content I have posted to any Stack Exchange website, deleted?

I wanted to do just that today, but I couldn't find anything on what rights I have as a user to have all my data completely removed.

Comment: If you want your personal data erased, you'll need to submit a [GDPR Request](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request). But as the other question explains, you cannot request all your content be deleted too.